# Deleting Temporary Internet Files through Group Policy

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, group-policy, files

I have a domain controller running on Windows 2008 Server R2 and users login to application servers on which Windows 2003 Server SP2 is installed. I have applied a Group Policy to clean temporary internet files on exit i.e to delete all temporary internet files when users close the browser. But the group policy doesn't seem to work as user profile size keeps on increasing and the major space is occupied by temporary internet files therefore increasing the disk usage. How can i enforce automatic deletion of temporary internet files?

Answer (score 1):

Use a script.  [There are a bunch here](http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/how-delete-temporary-internet-files-with-script-t25583.html).

EDIT:  Now that I think about, though, a better approach would probably be to just [limit the maximum cache size through GPO](http://www.petri.co.il/controlling_ie_cache_size_via_gpo.htm).  Profile sizes won't grow out of control because of temporary internet files, and your users won't have to cache new files every time they access a webpage, only to have those cache files blown away on a regular basis.