# How do I use Group Policy on a domain to delete Temporary Internet Files?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows, internet-explorer

I have a domain controller running on Windows 2008 Server R2 and users login to application servers on which Windows 2003 Server SP2 is installed. I have applied a Group Policy to clean temporary internet files on exit i.e to delete all temporary internet files when users close the browser. But the group policy doesn't seem to work as user profile size keeps on increasing and the major space is occupied by temporary internet files therefore increasing the disk usage. How can i enforce automatic deletion of temporary internet files?

Comment: Have you confirmed the GP is being applied to the application servers successfully?  Exactly which group policy did you apply?  Did you apply it to a container the computer accounts are in, or to a container the user accounts are in?

Comment: Run `RSoP.msc` to check which policies get applied to a particular computer and/or user (`gpresult` would work as well, but I always found the output a little hard to read). Another option would be to use `Group Policy Results` from the `Group Policy Editor`.

Comment: Where are you trying to delete the temporary files? On the 2003 server or the client workstations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting Temporary Internet Files through Group Policy](http://serverfault.com/questions/425776/deleting-temporary-internet-files-through-group-policy)

Comment: Ref to techie007's comment:

I have applied it on container the user accounts are in.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, it seems like XP does not support the GPO.  I've had to create a new ADM file, but I've yet to test it.

```
CLASS USER

CATEGORY "Custom Changes for Internet Explorer"

KEYNAME "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Cache"

    POLICY "Delete temporary internet files on close"
    VALUENAME "Persistent"
            VALUEON NUMERIC 0 
            VALUEOFF NUMERIC 1
    END POLICY
END CATEGORYY
```

For some reason I need the YY at the end of category, I'm sure I've never needed that before.